# WPF dynamically change Button highlight from template

Tags: wpf, templates, binding

I have a few Buttons that change Background color when pressed but, when I MouseOver, the Highlight color completely replaces the set Background.

I tried creating a custom template and changed Background value to Transparent in

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
</Trigger>
```

This kind of works, but only when there's no color set as the Button's background.

I tried completely removing the property, but then the mouse needs to be exactly on the text to trigger events, and still set the background to Null.

Is it possible in the template to dynamically bind that Property's Value to the current Background color?

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the Button's style that set its Background value to Null instead of Transparent.

Correcting that value and simply removing the Background property from the IsMouseOver trigger works as intended.